# How to convert trained models (ResNet) into inference-models PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

I trained the model and then saved it as shown in the figure (right side), and I would like to convert it as shown in the figure (left side).

I found the [script](https://github.com/thohemp/6DRepNet/blob/master/sixdrepnet/convert.py) for [RepVGG](https://github.com/DingXiaoH/RepVGG/blob/main/repvgg.py) using python.

I would like to know how I can convert for ResNet that I got the model from this [code](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose/blob/master/code/train_hopenet.py).

[image]

Comment: You ought to save your model with `torch.save`, and assuming that you use the same model code as the left one

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, I save the left one using: torch.save(model.state_dict(),
            'AFLW2000_epoch_50 + '.pkl') but how can I convert it to the right one?